# Restoring all data and dependencies from dpkg --set-selections '*'

Tags: package-management, dpkg, aptitude

So I can run on one machine:

```
dpkg --get-selections '*' > selection.txt
```

On another machine:

```
dpkg --set-selections < selection.txt
```

... followed by either of the following:

```
aptitude install
apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

... to install the packages that.

However, it appears that some information gets lost in the process, such as whether a package (say `xyz`) got installed automatically as dependency of another package (`abc`). You can see that whenever you do something like `apt-get --purge remove abc`. On the original machine you would be notified that package `xyz` was installed as dependency of `abc` and that you may use `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of it.

Now I am aware of `deborphan` and `debfoster`, but they're cumbersome to use given the (simple) task at hand.

It seems saving and restoring the selections as shown above is not sufficient to restore the subtle dependencies of installed packages.

Is there a way to back up the complete set of metadata for package management and restore it then in its entirety?

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing I generate a big shell script with a 'sudo apt-get install' with all my packages (minus libs). Of course, I run into the same problem you're having.

Comment: I would guess that the best place to start looking would be to check if dpkg is in fact responsible for that information. If it isn't then maybe that is apt's job.

Comment: If you're going the manual way, you may be interested in `apt-mark` for saving/restoring information about automatic vs manually installed packages

Comment: It's not in the 10.04 package repo, is it? Is this part of the Canonical repos or third-party?

Comment: It starts with the problem that on a fresh system, only a few packages are marked as automatically installed, when - from a dependency tree point of view - it should be the other way around.

Comment: @htorque: so you're saying there is no solution to the problem as such?

Comment: No, that's just a "for your information" comment. I'd use apt-mark (it's part of apt, so it should already be installed) to get and set the marks for the packages (see [its manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html) for details).

Comment: @htorque: thanks for the info then :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Backup:

```
apt-mark showauto > pkgs_auto.lst
apt-mark showmanual > pkgs_manual.lst
```

Restore:

```
sudo apt-mark auto $(cat pkgs_auto.lst)
sudo apt-mark manual $(cat pkgs_manual.lst)
```

Comment: Thanks, was about to ask that you or Lekensteyn write that up as an answer.

Comment: Does these commands allow you to reinstall the programs from that list?

Comment: can this *remove* packages that are installed extra, at restoration?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `auto` and `manual` ?  Thanks.

Comment: I accidentally marked as manual a bunch of other packages... is there a way to revert? Thanks

Comment: Mate! I wish I'd known this when I wrote my backup script, now that I'm trying to restore everything! ☹

Comment: And now that I'm trying to restore to my _next_ system, I'm getting a whole buncho' errors: 'Unable to locate package', 'can not be marked as it is not installed', etc. So I suppose what was required was _both_ `dpkg --get-selection` and these commands? :sigh: Maybe my next hardware transfer will go more smoothly.

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer to this question is incomplete and does not (or no longer) works.  The painful fix is to use a bash for-loop to parse the output *.lst files and feed them to `apt install`.  Bad choice, though, so will not be illustrated here.

A better choice is to use `apt-clone`, as seen in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191676/4193) on the Unix & Linux Stackexchange.  This creates a small file (around 100K or less for my system).  Allegedly, it will clone the packages with little effort or pain.

So, in short, on the original machine:

```
apt-clone clone `uname -n`
```

Then, on the machine to clone to, copy the clone file and run:

```
apt-clone restore original-machine-name.apt-clone.tar.gz
```

I include this answer here since this page turned up in initial web searches, but the other answer did not.  This method looks way easier.