# Upgrade Problem with 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade from ubuntu 12.04, but the update manager doesn't show me that any upgrades are available. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this documentation : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

In your case since you are under 12.04, I think you will have to dist-upgrade twice... So you may consider a clean install. I mean, backup your system (system and data partitions), in case something goes wrong and you want to get back to your actual configuration. Download Ubuntu 13.04 an install it... If you have 2 partitions '/' and 'home' you can re-use them during the installation. You just have to tell the installer that you don't want to format your 'home' partition so only you system will be re-install. If everything goes well you will recover you data and don't even need your backups. The only thing you will have to do is re-installing and configuring your system.

You could save the list of your installed package and restore it with this command :

dpkg --get-selections > packages.txt

Once your new install is done you can restore your packages like this :

dpkg --set-selections < packages.txt

Forgot you will need these commands after the precedent to effectively restore your packages (installed them) :

aptitude install

apt-get -u dselect-upgrade

Reference about get-selections : [Restoring all data and dependencies from dpkg --set-selections '*'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101931/restoring-all-data-from-backup-of-dpkg-set-selections)

Richard