# reducing existing installation to minimal

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-minimal

I am renting a VPS with Ubuntu Server 16.04 preinstalled from an image. It however comes with a lot of unneeded packages, I wish they had offered Ubuntu Minimal (but they don't).

So, I would like to remove packages from my current installation, to end up with Ubuntu minimal. How can I do this? Is there a script that I can execute, or a list of packages that I need to uninstall to end up with a vanilla Ubuntu Minimal

[I'm aware of [How to convert existing Ubuntu install to minimal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987560/how-to-convert-existing-ubuntu-install-to-minimal) but the solution there doesn't apply to me, since I cannot manually change or reinstall the OS, only delete packages that I don't use.]

Comment: Whatever you do, do NOT remove anything Python or Python 3

Comment: I don't want to be something just to provide non-advice but well Ubuntu doesn't have a Ubuntu Minimal version because Ubuntu isn't minimal. Both Debian and Fedora can be made to be quite minimal. That isn't to say Ubuntu can't be made to be minimal just its far from its intended use case.

Comment: @jdwolf  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thats a minimal installer not a minimal install. (meaning during instlal it grabs packages online).

Comment: @jdwolf Well, your previous comment said "Ubuntu version", not "minimal install". And yes, Ubuntu doesn't have minimal install option, that's why OP is asking.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thats semantics. We're talking about installed ubuntu pretty obviously. Depending on distribution there is a "minimal version" and other distributions there may or may not be a minimal version but making it minimal through the installer is possible. Debian for example doesn't have a "minimal" version either but their installs give options to make the installed OS minimal. Fedora actually has a minimal version through its spins system. Simply unchecking everything in the ubuntu installer doesn't leave you with a minimal install comparatively.

Comment: @jdwolf  Yes, I'm  aware of such options for Fedora and I believe CentOS as well, but as far as Ubuntu goes - the minimal CD version is the best there is, and as OP mentioned their provider doesn't have that option. In fact I think most VPS providers don't offer that, only standard Ubuntu versions. Semantics aside, I am completely with you that there's no such option in the installer and it would be great to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the minimal and the normal installation options is just that canonical removed a few packages from being installed by default. The difference is fairly small, around 400mb in total installation size. You can simply remove the packages that you do not need with `sudo apt remove PACKAGENAME` or `sudo apt purge PACKAGENAME`.

To answer the question, here is a list of all the packages that have been removed if you install the 18.04 with the minimal option. A similar list for ubuntu-mate [can be found here.](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/ubuntu-seeds/ubuntu-mate.bionic/view/head:/desktop.minimal-remove)

```
# This is a list of packages to be removed when the 'minimal' option is
# selected during installation.

# Note that the format is NOT the same as the usual seed format. This file is
# not processed by germinate - it is simply downloaded during image builds.

# Desktop apps
thunderbird
transmission-gtk
gnome-todo
baobab
rhythmbox
cheese
vino
shotwell
totem
usb-creator-gtk
deja-dup
gnome-calendar
remmina
simple-scan

# Desktop experience
thunderbird-gnome-support

# Games
aisleriot
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-mines
gnome-sudoku
branding-ubuntu

# Libreoffice
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-writer
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-ogltrans
libreoffice-pdfimport

# Others
example-content
ubuntu-web-launchers

# Langpacks (keeping libreoffice and thunderbird installed otherwise)
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
libreoffice-l10n-es
libreoffice-l10n-zh-cn
libreoffice-l10n-zh-tw
libreoffice-l10n-pt
libreoffice-l10n-pt-br
libreoffice-l10n-de
libreoffice-l10n-fr
libreoffice-l10n-it
libreoffice-l10n-ru
libreoffice-l10n-en-za
libreoffice-help-en-gb
libreoffice-help-es
libreoffice-help-zh-cn
libreoffice-help-zh-tw
libreoffice-help-pt
libreoffice-help-pt-br
libreoffice-help-de
libreoffice-help-fr
libreoffice-help-it
libreoffice-help-ru
libreoffice-help-en-us
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
thunderbird-locale-es
thunderbird-locale-es-ar
thunderbird-locale-es-es
thunderbird-locale-zh-cn
thunderbird-locale-zh-hans
thunderbird-locale-zh-hant
thunderbird-locale-zh-tw
thunderbird-locale-pt
thunderbird-locale-pt-br
thunderbird-locale-pt-pt
thunderbird-locale-de
thunderbird-locale-fr
thunderbird-locale-it
thunderbird-locale-ru

# Unused rdepends
gir1.2-rb-3.0
gir1.2-totem-1.0
gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
guile-2.0-libs
libabw-0.1-1
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
libdmapsharing-3.0-2
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
libfreehand-0.1-1
libgnome-games-support-1-3
libgnome-games-support-common
libgom-1.0-0
libgrilo-0.3-0
liblangtag-common
liblangtag1
libmessaging-menu0
libmhash2
libminiupnpc10
libmwaw-0.3-3
libmythes-1.2-0
libnatpmp1
libneon27-gnutls
liborcus-0.13-0
libpagemaker-0.0-0
librdf0
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-gtk3
libreoffice-style-elementary
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-tango
libraptor2-0
librasqal3
librevenge-0.0-0
librhythmbox-core10
libtotem0
libvisio-0.1-1
libwpd-0.10-10
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.4-4
libyajl2
python3-uno
rhythmbox-data
rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
rhythmbox-plugins
remmina-common
remmina-plugin-rdp
remmina-plugin-secret
remmina-plugin-vnc
duplicity
seahorse-daemon
shotwell-common
totem-common
totem-plugins
transmission-common
cheese-common
gnome-todo-common
libgnome-todo
gnome-video-effects
libcheese-gtk25
libcheese8
uno-libs3
ure
zeitgeist-core
hunspell-de-at-frami
hunspell-de-ch-frami
hunspell-de-de-frami
hunspell-en-au
hunspell-en-ca
hunspell-en-gb
hunspell-en-za
hunspell-es
hunspell-fr
hunspell-fr-classical
hunspell-it
hunspell-pt-br
hunspell-pt-pt
hunspell-ru
hyphen-de
hyphen-en-ca
hyphen-en-gb
hyphen-en-us
hyphen-fr
hyphen-hr
hyphen-it
hyphen-pl
hyphen-pt-br
hyphen-pt-pt
hyphen-ru
mythes-de
mythes-de-ch
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
mythes-fr
mythes-it
mythes-pt-pt
mythes-ru
```

Comment: Strange, here all sorts of other software comes pre-bundled (including apache2, php, etc.). Apparently they pre-installed more than just the vanilla server edition then. I think I'll use another approach, thanks for the info!