# want to get the all softwares and its details to make my system inventory

Tags: apt, software-center

Want to get the software details to get my system inventory to get the software packages i use this commands (dpkg -l)

It prints all the system applications also so i need to get the software only i manually installed

I have an idea to take from software center it will give the exact information of installed software so please help for this and thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find manually installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32007/how-to-find-manually-installed-packages) and [How to list user installed applications (not packages)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159664/how-to-list-user-installed-applications-not-packages)

Comment: First link i tried this which gives the every softwares like fonts and so on which is pre installed softwares in ubuntu i want to get the ubuntu software center installed files cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && cat *.list i tried from the second list it didn't show much it gives only the google stable list

Comment: The first question has 4 answers and the second question has 15 answers. Not every answer has what you want.

Comment: No have tried everything...Some have done but some softwares are missing which i manually installed

Comment: Manually installed how?

Comment: by command line or through software center