# How to find all programms installed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I know this an FAQ, but this is a little different. My primary disk fails to boot, so I have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a new disk.

The old disk is still readable, so can I find a list of all ot the programs that were installed on it, so I can install them on the new disk?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/360536/225694) in the called duplicate should work. Just change the path to include the mount point of the old disk.

Comment: I don't quite see how this question is substantially different from the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will give you exactly what you want but you can try it and see:

```bash
apt list --installed > file_of_installed_prog
```

Comment: 'apt list --installed' gives me a list of the programs installed on my 'new' machine. However the suggestion in the 'Welcome' message regarding /var/log/apt/history.log may help. Probably a lot of faff, but I should get there. NOTE TO SELF - run 'apt list --installed' on a regular basis and keep the resulting list. This isn't the first time this has happened to me!